# Determine Dialog Minimization from within a control

Tags: c++, mfc, controls, minimization, window-messages

Is there any way to determine a minimization of a Dialog from within a control which is on the dialog?

I'm using the window message `ON_WM_SIZE` which should be called with the Type `SIZE_MINIMIZED` when the dialog gets minimized.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEditT, CEdit)
   ON_WM_SIZE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CEditT::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
   CEdit::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);
   switch(nType)
   {
      case SIZE_MINIMIZED:
         m_backgroundRedraw = TRUE;
   }
}
```

However this method never gets called, when the Dialog is being minimized. I need to track that minimization in order to correctly redraw my control with transparencies when it's being restored again.

Answer (score 0):

First find the parent dialog from within your control using

```
CWnd *parent = GetParent();
HWND hWnd = parent->GetSafeHwnd();  // get its window handle
BOOL dlgMinimized = IsMinimized(hWnd);   // get min. state
```

The API is documented as:

```
BOOL WINAPI IsIconic(
  _In_  HWND hWnd
);
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633527%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

IsMinimized is a macro defined in windowsx.h and corresponds to IsIconic as documented by Microsoft.

I would suggest a different method. Catch the SIZE_MAXIMIZED nType in your Dialog OnSize() method, and maintain this state in a member variable. Then you can check it from the children setting up a WM_USER+XXX message handler in the dialog to respond with the current value.

At this point, you need to SendMessage(WM_USER+XXX,...) from a part of the code in your child control that actually gets called so it can perform some task. To see what messages are send to/from the child, I would check with spy++.

Comment: Okay 2 questions. Where is that IsMinimized method from? And where would you suggest calling this? WM_ERASEBKGND and WM_PAINT are only called when the window is not minimized!

Answer (score 0):

This does not need to be that complicated.  You should trap the WM_SYSCOMMAND message on the dialog level.  That message handles minimize events. Then, simply call an exposed method of the control in response to that event.